# Не могу подключиться к Mysql серверу в visual studio 2019

Tags: mysql, wpf, ado.net, visual-studio-2019

[image]

Пытаюсь создать модель ADO.Net
при подключении к серверу появляется такая ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, строку подключения, которую вы используете для коннекта с БД?

Comment: app.config? 
я не могу подключиться к бд. Именно из-за ошибки, которая указана выше.
Я использую функционал для подключения к бд, который предлагает visual studio при создании модели

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded 

попробуйте вот это

Comment: попробовал поменять на mysql_native_password. 
выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: VS сама по себе не умеет работать с MySql. Вы установили какой-то коннектор. Какой именно?

Comment: MySql for visual studio 2.0.5
Connector/NET 8.0.21
в Visual Studio пакеты nuget: EntityFramework 6 и MySql.Data